# convert json file to a list as test

Tags: python, json, list

there are few json files in a directory and making transformations in each file for that I want to read each file as a list filename[] and make changes and output into 1 file, where the output for every input file should be appended and a line added between each files data.

```
path = './json'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.json')):
    print(filename)
    tm = json.load(open(filename))
    sample = tm[filename]
    print(tm[filename])
```

not sure if I'm writing as a list correctly, running into a keyError

Comment: Add `print(filename)` and see

Comment: That is there already :) 
Able to print the filename.

Comment: Can you give an example of how the json is formatted?

Comment: {
  "abc": {
    "abc": "abc"
  },
  "xyz": "cvdb",
  "abdc": "abdc",
  "hj": {
    "hj1": "klm"
  },
  "dghs": [
    {
      "dh1": "a",
      "dh2": "b",
      "dh3": "c"
    }],
  "url" : [
    "[fhskl](url)"
    ]
  }

Something like this, trying to print out as a list everything wrapped in [] as list

Comment: Is the filename the key of anything in that json? Right now you are doing `tm[filename]`

Comment: it is not, the filename is not in the file, trying to convert to a list.

Comment: that was good pointer, changed that and it worked.